# The "ValidateAppxPackage" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

While creating my export for Windows Store I am having this issue.

Simple export works fine but when I try to create a build for windows store I am having this error:

```
The "ValidateAppxPackage" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.ValidateAppxPackage.<>c.<CheckThatLanguagesAreSupported>b__85_0(XElement resource)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.ValidateAppxPackage.CheckThatLanguagesAreSupported()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.ValidateAppxPackage.ExecuteImplementation()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.AppxPackagingTaskHelper.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.ValidateAppxPackage.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SeedRateCalculator
```

I don't know what to do. I am using VS 2015 and creating build of my **Universal Windows App**.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new UWP and do a copy paste of all your files?

Comment: I created a new project and it started to work fine..Then I compared my old manifest file with the new one and realize it was my supporting language that was creating trouble..Thanks for your suggestion...You gave me the right direction that leads me to the real problem....

Comment: Glad I could help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On msdn some people solved the problem in this way:

- I fixed the problem by deleting the StoreAssociation file, making it
  rebuild it. Thanks!
- I decided to move the app folder to another location, and ran Visual
  Studio in admin mode (with admin privileges) and it started working

Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I normally delete my obj and bin folder before try to pack things up, I used to run into all sorts of trouble, also do a "Clean solution" just for good measure (Right click solution => Clean solution).

If the problem still persists then delete the Package.StoreAssociation.xml and [your_app_name]_StoreKey.pfx then associate with store again (Right click on project => Store => Associate ...) and then try to package it.

Should be straight forward.

Comment: You get the same error message? 
Could you link the whole error message?

Comment: Task 'ValidateAppxPackage' failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I added the complete error in my question...You can see above

Comment: I'm not quite sure, have you tempered with your application manifest? 
"CheckThatLanguagesAreSupported" fails it would suggest that your language selection(s) causing some issues.

Comment: It was my supporting language that creating trouble...I realized it yesterday when I create a new project and compare manifest file of my old project with the new project manifest...I replace my "<Resource Language="en-us"/>" with the <Resource Language="x-generate" />...and it started to work...Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same problem on an [App that has been in the store for years](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/magic-led-lights/9nblggh10fch?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), I just fixed a bug, built new packages, run verification on VS2017 and I get this on the Bytecode generation tests, and so all subsequent tests also fail.  So I deleted Package.StoreAssociation.xml and tried to re-associate the app with the store, but when I did that it did not create a new Package.StoreAssociation.xml.  So I had to restore the old Package.StoreAssociation.xml, then re-associate the app with the store, and I see a bunch of updates, so clearly this needs to happen - seems broken that this didn't happen automatically when I created my store packages the first time.  But this also didn't solve the problem, I still get this when trying to verify the app:

```
Bytecode generation
```

Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.Utility.IsPackageWWA(AppXPackage package) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.BytecodeGenerationCheck.BytecodeGenerationCheck.ExecuteSharedValidation(String manifestFilePath, String packageFullName) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()